# PayPal IPN Adding your own data onto IPN message

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have integrated PayPal into my website and have the IPN system working successfully. The problem I have now is that unless the PayPal email is the same as the one they used to register on my site, I have no idea who the person is.

I would like to add on my own data to the IPN message such as `AccountID=10` or `AccountName="SomeName"` so that I can identify who the person is for my own user base since it is selling of virtual goods and privileges and not shipping to some address. Can this be done?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helps or if I misunderstood something and you need any further/other info

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can send many parameters such as `invoice` parameter with your Paypal IPN request and get it returned with IPN response.
Full parameters list is available here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Answer (score 0):

You could also make this a non-issue by setting it up so your customers use their PayPal login credentials to log into your site. Have a look at the following documentation:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/identity/log-in-with-paypal/